# Find the height of a tree

Tags: c, data-structures

Can you make me understand this code to find the height of a binary tree:

```
   int lDepth = maxDepth(node->left);
   int rDepth = maxDepth(node->right);

   /* use the larger one */
   if (lDepth > rDepth) 
       return(lDepth+1);
   else return(rDepth+1);
```

I am not able to understand how  "**int lDepth = maxDepth(node->left);**" will return the height of left subtree as when it reaches the base case...it will return 0. (code is incomplete).

Comment: Do you understand the concept of [recursion](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Recursion)?

Comment: I know the basics of recursion...But i always get stuck in complicated statements or multiple use of recursion..

Comment: "when it reaches the base case...it will return 0.". Right, and notice that after calling `maxDepth` you add +1 before returning. So in the end you get `0+1+....+1`, with as many +1s as the tree is hight. That's basic recursion.

Comment: @sarabjotsingh this *is* basic recursion. You don't want to look at complicated recursions.

Comment: wow....That's what i was guessing...thanx..Can you please suggest some good tutorials to strong my topic "recursion" altough i know the basics..@tux3

Comment: @Erigrith.... i know....but i am new to it :(

Comment: @sarabjotsingh Try to code this or something similar yourself, without copying other people's code. You'll get familiar with the concept if you actually use it successfully.

Comment: @sarabjotsingh It's okay to be new to something. In fact, the more things you are new to the more things you are discovering. Google "C code recursion tutorial" I think you might find what you need

Answer (score 2):

> i am not able to understand how "int lDepth = maxDepth(node->left);"
>   will return the height of left subtree as when it reaches the base
>   case...it will return 0. (code is incomplete).

True it will return 0, but don't forget the +1, imagine it reaches a case where the tree has a left and right node (no grandchild), the height of the left is 0 and of the right is 0 so depth of the parent is the depth of largest +1 which is 1